# Detect a similar request sent to php from same client in a little time difference

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script that receives $_['post'] data from a button in flash , some times the user does double click on that button and the data sends twice , it causes mysql update conflict in server side .
How can i ignore the further requests in php from the same client in a little time diffrence?

Comment: I imagine it would be easier to disable the button in flash after the first submit.

Comment: you are right but i have not access to flash file

Comment: What kind of update conflicts? Have you already thought about [transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html)?

Comment: Could possibly have it set in a $_SESSION variable to see when they last successfully inserted into your db. If they then submit again and not enough time has elapsed, it will prevent the insert... just an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not have a last updated timestamp in the database and then check that against the current time.  If it's in the last couple of seconds, then don't run the MySQL query.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever heard of [locking tables in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html)?

It's not possible to provide detailed example without you providing more details, but basic example would be:

```
mysql_query( "LOCK TABLES updates READ WRITE", $connection);
$q = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM updates WHERE user = $currentUser AND time...");
if( mysql_result($q, 0, 0) != 0){
    // Someone's already doing update; exit
    mysql_query( "UNLOCK TABLES;");
    return false;
}

// Require lock for ourselves
mysql_query( "INSERT INTO updates ...");
mysql_query( "UNLOCK TABLES;");

// Do the stuff on database
```

This makes sure that when the same user will try to do this twice he or she won't be allowed to (just one update at the time).

You have also different options:

- Use [`TRANSACTION`](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&q=mysql%20transactions)
- Generate one time token for updating (beware of atomicity, you'd have to execute `DELETE FROM ...` and then check affected rows, because `SELECT; DELETE` my get interrupted or you'd have to use table locking again)
- And my favourite one: `button.enable=false`, and on request completed `button.enabled=true`

<sub>Note: the code is vulnerable against SQL Injection and you `mysql_` functions are outdated.</sub>

Comment: is there any locking mode to prevent just the same user from updating table?

Comment: @manfilsoof no, that's why the table is locked just for the shortest period of time possible. This is only 2-4 database queries which could be really fast (providing correct database design and usage of indexes) before table is unlocked again. Try to benchmark it or try to measure estimated time :) I believe this is quite common practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can add basic protection mechanism, as you can add a hidden random value to the form and maintain a table of displayed values, from which you delete the used ones before executing the main query. This would also prevent XSS.